# How can I get all (or pick one) the registered email accounts on iOS device (for current user)

Tags: ios

In iOS Settings/Contacts/Accounts user can add different e-mail accounts.
How can I retrieve them programmatically? At least email and provider name.
Or open a picker with them like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager

Comment: You can't get the user's email address(es) programmatically. That would be a privacy violation. You can provide a text field for them to enter an email address. If you set its content type to email then iOS will suggest email addresses for the user on the quick bar.

Comment: But if user is presented with picker and he/she picks an account and explicitly grants access it is not. What Windows and Android provide

Comment: That's not an available function in iOS.  It would be difficult to provide that function securely. The picker would need to be presented out of process in order to prevent a malicious app from introspecting the view hierarchy and leaking the email addresses. Maybe Android and Windows have done this or maybe they don't think about privacy as much as Apple does.

Comment: Looking at the Microsoft function you linked to, it is different to what you are asking for; it allows a user to select from currently known Identity provider identifies and complete oauth authentication to gain a token. This is very different to getting a list of email accounts.

Comment: I need what MS does. They call a broker which is an external app built by MS and called via Windows 10 API.

Comment: You can either filter from which provider to present accounts or add your command to sign in with any other identity provider

Comment: You can use the MSAL framework for iOS to perform a brokered authentication against Azure AD (enterprise or B2C). There are also equivalent authentication frameworks for other providers, such as Google, Facebook and Twitter, but there is no general purpose authentication framework built in to iOS.